# Select room availability between date (sql Query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have some problem with SQL query. I'm looking for an available room between date from input form.

This is the table schema:

**Table Room**

- id_room, room_name, alootment
- ex : 1, vip, 10

**Table Price**

- id_price, id_room, price, date
- ex : 1, 1, 10, 2014-05-1 | 1, 1, 20, 2014-05-2 | 1, 1, 10, 2014-05-3

Table Booking

- id_booking, id_room, date
- ex : 1, 1, 2014-05-1 | 2, 1, 2014-05-1 | 3, 1, 2014-05-1

What I'm looking for is:

If there are people booking vip room from `2014-5-1` to `2014-05-3` with room quantity is 8

Then return blank (because vip room have 10 allotment and on 2014-05-1 are 3 booking, so just 7 room left)

**this is sql query**

```
select room_name, COUNT( SELECT FROM booking WHERE date between '$checkin' and '$checkout') as total_booking, from room where allotment <= total_boking
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this MySQL?

Syntax error; Also, `date` is a reserved name. See my revised tables and SQL below.

```
SELECT
    room.room_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking WHERE booking.booking_date BETWEEN '' AND '') AS     total_booking
FROM
room
WHERE room.allotment <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM booking WHERE booking.booking_date BETWEEN '' AND '')
```

Here is the table schema;

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `booking`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `booking`;
CREATE TABLE `booking` (
`id_booking` int(10) NOT NULL,
`id_room` int(10) NOT NULL,
`booking_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `price`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `price`;
CREATE TABLE `price` (
`id_price` int(10) NOT NULL,
`id_room` int(10) NOT NULL,
`price` int(10) NOT NULL,
`price_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `room`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `room`;
CREATE TABLE `room` (
`id_room` int(10) NOT NULL,
`room_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`allotment` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_room`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: yes arun this code on php, i have error result to. tq for feedback

Comment: I made a slight change. MySQL has nothing to do with php as php can use other databases. It would not hurt to include your php code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to write your query as:

```
select room_name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM booking b
        WHERE b.id_room = r.id_room and date between '$checkin' and '$checkout'
       ) as total_booking
from room r
having allotment <= total_booking;
```

Note that the subquery is now correlated with the outer query, so `total_booking` is for each room.

This also uses a MySQL extension where you can use column aliases defined in the `select` clause for filtering by using the `where` clause.